# Pinning icons to corners of flexbox container with flex-start and flex-end

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I have a video container. When the video is not playing, I'd like three things available:

- Icon or initials of remote user (top left corner)
- Video play icon (center)
- expand / contract (bottom right corner)

I've tried to push the icons to the corners using `align-self: flex-start` and `align-self: flex-end`, but they are not going to the corners. At the same time I want the video icon centered in the box.

So far I have this:

[image]
[image]

My SCSS:

```
.video-container {
  width: 270px;
  height: 202px;
  border: 1px solid #cececc;
  background-color: $grey-light;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  .top-left {
    align-self: flex-start;
  }
  .bottom-right {
    align-self: flex-end;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class='video-container' id='remote-media' data-target='video.remoteContainer'>
    <span class='top-left'>
      <%= concept(Avatar::Cell,@meeting.invitee_id,current_user: current_user ) %>
    </span>
    <i class="fa fa-video fa-3x"></i>
    <span class='video-expand bottom-right'>
      <i class="far fa-expand-arrows-alt fa-2x" data-target='video.expand' data-action='click->video#expand'></i>
      <i class="far fa-compress-alt fa-2x display-none" data-target='video.contract' data-action='click->video#contract'></i>
    </span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what I did is

1. set the `flex-direction` property of your `#video-container` to `column`
2. added `justify-content:space-between;` property to your `#video-container`
   3.used `align-self`property to align the child elements in to different places

it's working fine.

```css
#video-container{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

#video-container>span{
  border:1px solid #000;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  
}


.center{
  align-self:center;
}

.bottom-right{
  float:right;
  align-self:flex-end;
 }
```

```html
<div id="video-container">
  <span class="top-left"></span>
  <span class="center"></span>
  <span class="bottom-right"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by css positioning

Please check the following fiddle

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/sqc1a4Ln/1/)

```
   .topLeft, .bottomRight{
    position:absolute;
    }
```

Now used normal CSS and you can convert that to your SCSS

Answer (score 0):

```css
.video-container {
  width: 270px;
  height: 202px;
  border: 1px solid #cececc;
  background-color: $grey-light;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  .top-left {
    align-self: flex-start;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  .bottom-right {
    align-self: flex-end;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
  }
}
```

Using 'align-self' could't fix with position. So, try to add the relative and absolute position to solve these. Refer the above code.